# Does IE8 have issues with JS switches?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am building a piece of javascript that needs to be IE8 compatible.  When testing my code, IE8 gets tripped up on my switch. I am unable any good documentation on why it would do this. So what I am looking for is a good resource or answer why this snippet of code is getting tripped up:

```
$div.attr('shippingtotal', price.trim());
            switch (method.trim().toUpperCase()) {
            case 'STANDARD GROUND':
                $div.attr('value', 'UG');
                break;
            case 'THIRD DAY GROUND':
                $div.attr('value', 'UTS');
                break;
            case 'SECOND DAY AIR':
                $div.attr('value', 'US');
                break;
            case 'NEXT DAY':
                $div.attr('value', 'UNN');
                break;
            }
```

The console error says it is coming from line 40 which falls on the third break.

Comment: what does the error say? can you create a fiddle to demonstrate this?

Comment: IE8 and older are notoriously unreliable when it comes to giving errors' line numbers. Can you show the full error message, please?

Comment: You should be using `.val(newvalue)` to set element values, not `.attr()`. *edit* though in this case if `$div` is really a `<div>` node then I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: The error that is presented is "Object doesn't support this property or method."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no problem with your `switch`. Try to use `if-else` instead of that, I am sure you will get the same error.

```
$div.attr('shippingtotal', price.trim());
var ucMethod = method.trim().toUpperCase();
if (ucMethod == 'STANDARD GROUND')
    $div.attr('value', 'UG');
else if (ucMethod == 'THIRD DAY GROUND')
    $div.attr('value', 'UTS');
else if (ucMethod == 'SECOND DAY AIR')
    $div.attr('value', 'US');
else if (ucMethod == 'NEXT DAY')
    $div.attr('value', 'UNN');
```

or

```
var valueMap = {
    'STANDARD GROUND': 'UG',
    'THIRD DAY GROUND': 'UTS',
    'SECOND DAY AIR': 'US',
    'NEXT DAY': 'UNN'
};

$div.attr('shippingtotal', price.trim());
$div.attr('value', valueMap[method.trim().toUpperCase()]);
```

You should not rely on ie8 error messages. You should write unit tests instead. I think it is possible to run them with [karma](https://github.com/karma-runner). I guess the jquery has problems with ie8, but I am not sure...

I don't think ie8 support the [`trim()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) method. You should use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

Comment: IE8 was having issues with .trim.  It was resolved by restructuring a little and using jQuery:

$div.attr('shippingtotal', $.trim(price));
switch ($.trim(method).toUpperCase()) {

Comment: Linking to w3schools? Seriously?!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not the switch but the use of [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim). It's [**not implemented**](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#String.prototype.trim) in IE8 and you need to polyfill it or use a lib that has a trim function e.g. [`jQuery.trim`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).